# TFS 2013 Update 4 relase notes

Tags: update, team-foundation-server

We have encountered possible bug in source control while merging branches and thought it might be a reported bug. Currently we have Team Foundation Server 2013 Update 3 and I try to find release notes about Update4, but without any results.
Microsoft has posted a lot about Visual Studio updates, but none about TFS.

**Please help to find TFS Update4 release notes - particulary bugfix section.**

Short info of problem : have DEV branch, created new branch by changeset 5000 [of 7000 changesets in total]. When opening merging window to continue merging, older changesets with numbers like 2444 and 3567 appears to be unmerged.

Comment: There hasn't been a bugfix in this area as long back as I can remember.

Comment: @jessehouwing - maybe you know where to find all TFS reported bugs?

Comment: Release notes are here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2994375

Comment: There is no such location. Microsoft doesn't publish the complete list of changes to TFS anywhere publically.

Comment: Is my problem related to Visual Studio and not TFS?

Comment: We do not have enough information to be able to tell. Was this the first time the dev branch was created with this name? Or is it a recreation of an old branch?

Comment: I was asking about VS or TFS for this question - is my problem source VS or TFS? Is merging process (and encountered bug) happening in client siede (VS) or server-side (TFS)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51282/discussion-between-kristaps-vilerts-and-jessehouwing).